# Preset/Prepopulate value for input type number in angular js

Tags: json, angularjs

I am new to angular js. I have an input field of type number. I want to pre-populate it with a value that comes from a json file.

This does not work when I assign the value using ng-model. It works on a regular input of type text though.

I have also tried using ng-value directive and the value attribute. But no luck.

Need help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using a number in the JSON and not passing it back as a string. For eg. {"numberValue" : 50} and not {"numberValue": "50"}

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem

Answer (score 0):

As the ng-model acts like a two-way data binding, scope->view and view->scope you should assign that initial value within the controller initialization rather than using `ng-model` or the `value` attribute within the html markup.

```
    angular.module('MyApp.controllers',['MyAPP']).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location) {
      // This object will be filled by the form

      $scope.user = {};
      //Prepopulated value
      $scope.user.yearOfBirth=1911;
      ...
```